# How to graph relationships between points with Geopandas and Neo4j data?

Tags: neo4j, geopandas

I have a simple Neo4J database of Roads, with cities(nodes) that has latitude, longitude, id and roads with relationships GO.

For example:
`MATCH (city) RETURN (city) LIMIT 5`

```
    {"latitude":"41.974556","id":"0","longitude":"-121.904167"} 
    {"latitude":"41.974766","id":"1","longitude":"-121.902153"} 
    {"latitude":"41.988075","id":"2","longitude":"-121.896790"} 
    {"latitude":"41.998032","id":"3","longitude":"-121.889603"} 
    {"latitude":"42.008739","id":"4","longitude":"-121.886681"}
```

and
`MATCH (n1)-\[r\]-(n2) RETURN "GO", n1.id, n2.id LIMIT 4`

| "GO" | "n1.id" | "n2.id" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "GO" | "0" | "1" |
| "GO" | "0" | "3" |
| "GO" | "1" | "0" |
| "GO" | "1" | "2" |

With the follow code I can create a graph with the nodes over the map:

```
    from py2neo import Graph
    import pandas as pd
    import geopandas
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

    port = "7687"
    user = "****"
    pswd = "*****"    

    try:
        graph = Graph('bolt://localhost:'+port, auth=(user, pswd))
        print('SUCCESS: Connected to the Neo4j Database.')
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR: Could not connect to the Neo4j Database. See console for details.')
        raise SystemExit(e)    

    df = pd.DataFrame(graph.run("MATCH (n:Road) RETURN n.id, n.latitude, n.longitude").to_table(),columns=['ID','Latitude','Longitude']) 
    df.head()
    gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))    

    world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
    ax = world[world.continent == 'North America'].plot(color='white', edgecolor='black')    

    gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='red')
    plt.show()
```

I don't know how can graph the relationships between the nodes.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example of plotting using [`GeoPandas.GeoDataFrame.plot()`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot.html) the geometry of the GeoDataFrame is point data (lat/lon coordinates from the `Road` nodes stored in Neo4j). To plot the relationships using this method you'd need  the geometry for lines connecting the road nodes (intersections) as well.

I just went through a similar exercise with airport and flight data, perhaps you can adapt to your data.

First, in my Cypher query to fetch data that will later be loaded into a GeoDataFrame I find every flight using the pattern `(:Airport)-[:FLIGHT_TO]->(:Airport)` as I want each row in my GeoDataFrame to be a flight route between two airports. I also calculate weighted degree centrality for each airport so we can style node size relative to centrality in the plot. We also generate [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) for the airport location (POINT) as well as the flight (LINESTRING).

```py
AIRPORT_QUERY = """
  MATCH (origin:Airport)-[f:FLIGHT_TO]->(dest:Airport)
  CALL {
   WITH origin
   MATCH (origin)-[f:FLIGHT_TO]-()
   RETURN sum(f.num_flights) AS origin_centrality
  }
  CALL {
   WITH dest
   MATCH (dest)-[f:FLIGHT_TO]-()
   RETURN sum(f.num_flights) AS dest_centrality
  }
  RETURN {
    origin_wkt: "POINT (" + origin.location.longitude + " " + origin.location.latitude + ")",
    origin_iata: origin.iata, 
    origin_city: origin.city, 
    origin_centrality: origin_centrality, 
    dest_centrality: dest_centrality,
    dest_wkt: "POINT (" + dest.location.longitude + " " + dest.location.latitude + ")",
    dest_iata: dest.iata, 
    dest_city: dest.city, 
    length: f.length,
    num_flights: f.num_flights,
    geometry: "LINESTRING (" + origin.location.longitude + " " + origin.location.latitude + "," + dest.location.longitude + " " + dest.location.latitude + ")"
    
    } 
  AS airport
"""
```

The Neo4j Python Driver has a [`to_df()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/api.html#neo4j.Result.to_df) method which we can use to convert the result set from our Cypher query into a Pandas DataFrame. Then when we create the Geopandas GeoDataFrame we can parse the WKT returned by the Cypher statement into Shapely geometries.

```py
def get_airport(tx):
    results = tx.run(AIRPORT_QUERY)
    df = results.to_df(expand=True)
    df.columns=['origin_city','origin_wkt', 'dest_city', 'dest_wkt', 'origin_centrality', 'length', 'origin_iata', 'geometry','num_flights', 'dest_centrality', 'dest_iata']
    df['geometry'] = geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['geometry'])
    df['origin_wkt'] = geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['origin_wkt'])
    df['dest_wkt'] = geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['dest_wkt'])
    gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')
    return gdf
```

[image: A GeoDataFrame of US flights]

And now we're ready to plot the flights. We can dynamically set the marker size for the airports using the weighted degree centrality column for the airport.

```py
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

base = world[world.name == 'United States of America'].plot(color='white', edgecolor='black')

flights_gdf = flights_gdf.set_geometry("origin_wkt")
flights_gdf.plot(ax=base, markersize='origin_centrality')

flights_gdf = flights_gdf.set_geometry("geometry")
flights_gdf.plot(ax=base, markersize=0.1, linewidth=0.01)

plt.show()
```

[image: A plot of US airports and flights connecting them]

Hope that helps.